# M2: customer address increment_id column

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, customer-address

There's a column called `increment_id` in `customer_address_entity`. Is this used for anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that `customer_address_entity.increment_id` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Magento gives you the option to generate Human Friendly IDs for customer accounts. It's disabled by default. If you want to enable this feature, you can go to: `Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customers Configuration > Create New Account Options` and set `Generate Human-Friendly Customer ID` to `Yes`. That will generate Increment IDs for customer accounts.

Comment: I don't see `increment_id` getting populated with that option turned on for *addresses* (works for customer records).

Comment: Hmm... sorry, I thought you meant for the customer account. I've used that option before for the account.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the answer by the original author:

The increment_id serves no purpose at the moment, but can easily be transformed to a working one (although I see no business case for this).
In the column `eav_entity_type`, just add an increment_model for the entity `customer_address`. Then add an observer for `customer_address_save_before` and call that model to generate a new increment_id.